# I want to see all the cells in static table view, which don't appear on the screen in the storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm currently studying iOS programming in Swift. In creating a static table view, changing the Rows option more and increasing cells' height while designing them, there happens to be a problem:

The table doesn't scroll vertically in the storyboard. So it doesn't show all the cells I assigned in the Row option. I have more cells to work on. How can I handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see by following way

Select the controller in the story board
Go to size inspector and make it freeform , then you can increase the height of main view and can see the full content.

[image]

Comment: It works! Thank you for your kind explanation. You made my day. ^^

Comment: Oh, I forgot. Thanks again.